# arr.splice index inserts in all available indexes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

```
        const list = []
        const obj = {
          name: '',
          mobile: ''
        }
        _.forEach(errors, (value, key) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
          // debugger
          const field = key.split('.')[2]
          const index = key.split('.')[1]
          obj[field] = value[0]
          list.splice(index, 1, obj)
          console.log(obj)
        })
```

Above is the code I am working on. And below, is the screenshot, of the logs of each `obj` variable

[image]

What I want is to insert that object into the `index` of the `list` variable.

But what I get when the looping is done is

[image]

the last item in the loop overwrites everything in the `list` array.

By the way below shows the `index`

[image]

To sum it all up, I need the `obj` to be inserted to a specific `index` inside the `list` array.

**EDIT**

`errors` variable looks like this

[image]

And I need it to look something like this.

```
list = [
   { name: 'name error message here', mobile: 'error message here' },
   { name: 'name error message here', mobile: 'error message here' },
   { name: 'name error message here', mobile: 'error message here' },
   { name: 'name error message here', mobile: 'error message here' }
]
```

Comment: "*To sum it all up, I need the obj to be inserted to a specific index inside the list array.*" then shouldn't you just do `list[index] = obj`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r i am replacing the value with obj[field] = value[0]. If I instantiate the obj inside the foreach, the first three names will be gone.

Comment: @VLAZ i did that, but it behaves the same way with splice.

Comment: This question might be able to be simplified. What does `errors` look like (ie the input) and what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @BenAston i will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```js
function transform(data) {  
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((p, [key, [message]]) => {
    const keyElements = key.split('.')
    p[keyElements[1]] = p[keyElements[1]] || {}
    p[keyElements[1]][keyElements[2]] = message
    return p
  }, [])
}

const data = {
  'contacts.0.mobile': ["Error. Mobile number is a required field."],
  'contacts.0.name': ["Error. Contact name is a required field."],
  'contacts.1.mobile': ["Error. Mobile number is a required field."],
  'contacts.1.name': ["Error. Contact name is a required field."]
}
console.log(transform(data))
```

Or using a regular expression and named capture groups:

```js
   
const PATTERN = /contacts.(?<index>\d+).(?<type>\w+)/

function transform(data) {  
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((p, [key, [message]]) => {
    const { index, type } = PATTERN.exec(key).groups
    p[index] = p[index] || {}
    p[index][type] = message
    return p
  }, [])
}

const data = {
  'contacts.0.mobile': ["Error. Mobile number is a required field."],
  'contacts.0.name': ["Error. Contact name is a required field."],
  'contacts.1.mobile': ["Error. Mobile number is a required field."],
  'contacts.1.name': ["Error. Contact name is a required field."]
}
console.log(transform(data))
```

Comment: may I ask, what does `p[index] = p[index] || {}` mean

Comment: If an object does not already exist at that index, then add one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create `obj` outside the `forEach` loop and insert the same `obj` for all elements in `errors`. If you then update `obj` you will update all elements, since all elements are references to the same object. If you want each `index` to have its own object you should reflect that in your code.

```js
const errors = {
  "contacts.0.mobile": ["Error. Mobile number is a required field."],
  "contacts.0.name":   ["Error. Contact name is a required field." ],
  "contacts.1.mobile": ["Error. Mobile number is a required field."],
  "contacts.1.name":   ["Error. Contact name is a required field." ],
};

const list = [];
_.forEach(errors, (value, key) => {
  const [, index, field] = key.split(".");
  if (!list[index]) list.splice(index, 1, {name: "", mobile: ""});
  list[index][field] = value[0];
});

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The above will create a new object for each new `index` encountered.

Comment: Oh. I get it now, but when I tried this one, I only get the 'mobile' field and their values, and the 'name' fields are overwritten. How can I fix that ?

Comment: @Lucentyr To answer that I have to know what the contents of `errors` is and what the expected `list` result is. So I cannot answer that question with the info provided.

Comment: I updated the question with the content of the `errors` and my needed output for `list`.

Comment: with your updated comment, I only get the name values.

Comment: @Lucentyr I'm not entirely sure what you mean, I've changed the code block into a snippet and it seems to run just fine.